# jquery dom navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<p class="current" style="display: block; ">MD</p>
<input type="text" class="hidden" value="MD" style="display: none; ">
<p class="small hidden" style="display: none; ">MD, MBBS etc.</p>
<a class="save-field-data btn hidden" data-id="medical_degree" href="#" style="display: none; ">Save</a>
```

The above explains my Html dom elements. 
Say i am in a handler attached to the `class` `"save-field-data"`
How can i set the text of `class` `current`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.prevAll()` should help in this situation:

```
$('.save-field-data').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).prevAll('.current').eq(0)...
});
```

I added the `.eq(0)` to select the first match in-case there are several `.current` elements that are siblings of the clicked `.save-field-data` element.

Docs for `.prevAll()`: http://api.jquery.com/prevall

Note: the difference between `.prevAll()` and `.siblings()` is that `.prevAll()` only searches the sibling elements that precede the current selection and `.siblings()` will select all siblings no matter if they come before or after the current selection.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.save-field-data').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('p.current').html(' ... your html here ... ');
});
```

Comment: `$($(this).siblings('p.current')[0])` can just be `$(this).siblings('p.current')`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if im well off here but you can allways set by class like

```
$(".current").html("your text");
```

Or if you want the closest

```
$(this).closest(".current").html("your text");
```

Comment: [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches the parents of an element, not its siblings.